# Setting up a table layout in React Native

Tags: react-native

I'm transitioning a React project into React Native and need help setting up a grid layout in React Native. I want to set up a 5-col by x-row (number of rows may vary) view. I've played around with the react-native-tableview-simple package, but I can't specify the span of a cell. I've also tried the react-native-flexbox-grid package, which I'm able to set up columns, but I'm still not able to set the span-width of a specific cell. I wonder if there's anything I can use.

For reference, I would like my table to look something along the lines like this:

```
     |Col 1|Col 2|Col 3|Col 4|Col 5|
     |------------------------------
Row 1|     Text        | Yes |  No | 
     |------------------------------
Row 2|     Text        | Yes |  No | 
     |------------------------------
Row 3|     Text        |  Dropdown |
```

Answer (score 80, accepted):

You can do this without any packages. If each row is exactly the same doing the following should solve your problem;

```js
export default class Table extends Component {
    renderRow() {
      return (
            <View style={{ flex: 1, alignSelf: 'stretch', flexDirection: 'row' }}>
                <View style={{ flex: 1, alignSelf: 'stretch' }} /> { /* Edit these as they are your cells. You may even take parameters to display different data / react elements etc. */}
                <View style={{ flex: 1, alignSelf: 'stretch' }} />
                <View style={{ flex: 1, alignSelf: 'stretch' }} />
                <View style={{ flex: 1, alignSelf: 'stretch' }} />
                <View style={{ flex: 1, alignSelf: 'stretch' }} />
                </View>
        );
    }

    render() {
        const data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
        return (
            <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
            {
                data.map((datum) => { // This will render a row for each data element.
                        return this.renderRow();
                    })
            }
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: One question I have is that if I wanted to span a cell multiple columns, is there a way to specify that? Since my row/col layout is static right now, I can probably just set a fixed width to a cell to achieve this?

Comment: Doing that using flex is much better. If I were you I would give the renderRow function an array which specifies cell flex values. Afterwards on the style part of View's you just write flexVals[0], flexsVals[1] etc.
You can even use data.map there to make it cleaner. @jamesvphan

Comment: Ahhh gotcha, should've realized flex property determines width. And I will definitely go with the flex route as it's more responsive than using static values. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Your welcome mate. Remember you can also add stuff like minWidth, maxWidth to customize it even further @jamesvphan

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Aren't inline styles bad practice though?

Comment: Yes; it is usually not used in that way however this answer is more of a "how to do it" and not really about organization of code.

Answer (score 8):

After looking here for answers I discovered a really great library that behaves much like Bootstrap tables. I have found layout with React Native very challenging but this library delivers predictable layout results.

[React Native Easy Grid](https://github.com/GeekyAnts/react-native-easy-grid/)

I agree that basic flex tables should be built in to React Native but until they are this library worked great for me.

Comment: I like not having to add a dependency, but when it's something like this that's a pain and kinda ugly to write yourself, it can be so much better/easier/cleaner to just use a simple library to handle the heavy lifting. In my opinion, this is the way to go. Especially because it is well used and supported.

Answer (score 4):

Though it is an old post but I was looking for something similar asked in the question,

I have brainstormed and havoked the internet for the solution and the best solution I got was to import the **react-native-table-component** package to my project and prepare a decent table layout for my application to display data. There might be many more souls figuring out a way to do this and may I recommend this link to all your answers:[This link is the npm package installer link which have explanation to all the code and have examples](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-table-component)

Comment: Are there any TypeScript types for this?

Answer (score 4):

Using functional components:

(Specify the number of rows and columns in the array)

Create a Row component

```
function Row({ column }) {  
  return (
    <View style={styles.rowStyle}>
      {column.map((data) => (
        <Cell data={data} />
      ))}
    </View>
 );
}
```

Create a Cell component

```
function Cell({ data }) {
  return (
    <View style={styles.cellStyle}>
      <Text>{data}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Create a Grid component

```
function Grid() {
  const data = [
    [15, 14, 13, 12],
    [11, 10, 9, 8],
    [7, 6, 5, 4],
    [0, 1, 2, 3],
  ];
  return (
    <View style={styles.gridContainer}>
      {data.map((column) => (
        <Row column={column} />
      ))}
    </View>
  );
}
```

Style the components:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  gridContainer: {
      width: 220,
  },
  rowStyle: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "space-around",
  },
  cellStyle: {
    flex: 1,
    margin: 10,
  },
});
```

Comment: When I put it in horizontal scroll view it just shrunks to the width of character