# How to pass array to render in Flatlist in React Native

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native

I am getting issue in rendering a Flatlist in React native. The array is the output from a Google sheet via Node express. The array example is

```
[["Fateh","25"],["Fateh","100"],["Ambuja","140"],["Utcl","50"]]
```

What i have tried so far:

```
setDoList(() => {
                return [
                  {col1 : responseText[0], col2:responseText[1] ,key: Math.random().toString()}
                ]
              })
```

But indentation is not working here. I even tried to converting array into JS objects by using { ... array}, it didn't helped.
I am novice in the field of JS, please provide me direction to solve this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setting up a table layout in React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44357336/setting-up-a-table-layout-in-react-native)

Comment: Nope. Actually I just checked the type of array in React native app and it shows object. the result of Array.isArray(data) is false means the data after passing it through node JS it got converted and behaving like a string. thus index 0 is returning `[` instead of `["Fateh","25"]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to use array of arrays in flat list you can do something like this

```
export default function App(){    

    const array = ['["Fateh","25"]','["Fateh","100"]','["Ambuja","140"]','["Utcl","50"]'];

      return(
        <View style={styles.div}>
          <FlatList
            data={array}
            renderItem={({ item,index }) => {
                console.log("item is",item);
                var array = JSON.parse(item);
        return(
            <View style={{flexDirection:"row"}}>
            {array.map((item, key) => 
            {
                return(
                <View>
                  <Text> {item} </Text>
                </View>
              )
            })}
            </View>
        )
        } }
            keyExtractor={item => item.id}
          />
        </View>
      );

    }
```

You can use FlatList for each than you can use map inside it.

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: I got an error `undefined is not a function (near '...item.map...')`

Comment: Moreover, the data is no more array type after getting it from node JS. It is more like a string.

Comment: ["["Fateh","25"]","["Fateh","100"]","["Ambuja","140"]","["Utcl","50"]"] then it will be array of strings like this is it right.

Comment: If the inner data in array is string than I had edited my answer and it won't give any error as you mentioned (undefined is not a function (near '...item.map...')) check that once.

Answer (score 1):

On the React Native side. How about you use JSON.parse(data)before trying to access its properties or methods.

If it is a string you would need to convert it to an array of objects with JSON.parse().

Also, what does the data look like on the node js server-side before you send it to React Native? I know google sheets are known to do some strange things